# How to access a value from a user defined function which returns tabular output in kusto

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I have following user define function

```
let myFunction = ()
{
T
| where id ==12345
|mv-expand details.data
|extend CreateTime=todatetime(details_data.["time"])
|extend Code=tostring(details_data.code)
|summarize arg_max(CreateTime,Code)
};
```

Now i want to get the values of each column from above function which returns 1 row with 2 cloumns
**Something like**
|print T().CreateTime
|print T().Code

Can you please help me achieve the above.

Comment: Hi Gurdeep, does the answer below answer the question? If yes, please accept it :)  If not, please add a comment specifying what you're missing.

Answer (score 0):

The [toscalar()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/toscalarfunction) function will do exactly what you need:

Example:

```
let SomeResult =
    range n from 1 to 1000 step 1
    | extend r = 100 * rand()
    | summarize min(r), max(r), avg(r);
print toscalar(SomeResult | project min_r)
```

The result will be:

| print_0 |
| --- |
| 0.0437954709718918 |

Note that accessing a value in a specific column is done using the `project` operator.